# How to find what period of given timespans is currently

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I've been given 6 hour-and-minute timestamps which define a period of time, lets call them 1 trough 6.
(example: 03:13, 05:22, 12:54, 16:55, 20:23, 22:14)

For example: 1st period starts at 03:13 and lasts until 05:22 -1 minute, and so on

Naturally, at the end, periods must cover all 24 hours in a day so the sixth period (which starts at 22:14) will last until 03:13

What is the best/most optimal way to write a function that can tell what period of time we are currently in?

Here is my try (which doesn't work and is suboptimal):

```
    function currentPeriod(hrs, mins, now) {
       // hrs is an array of integers and they define only hours (3, 5, 12,...)
       // mins is an array of integers and they define minutes (13, 22, 54,...)
       // now is a JavaScript Date

       if(now.getHours() > 0 && now.getHours() < hrs[0]) { return 6; }
       else if(now.getHours() == hrs[0] && now.getMinutes() < mins[0]) { return 6; }
       else if(now.getHours() == hrs[0] && now.getMinutes() >= mins[0]) { return 1; }
    
       else if(now.getHours() > hrs[0] && now.getHours() < hrs[1]) { return 1; }
       else if(now.getHours() == hrs[1] && now.getMinutes() < mins[1]) { return 1; }
       else if(now.getHours() == hrs[1] && now.getMinutes() >= mins[1]) { return 2; }
    
       else if(now.getHours() > hrs[1] && now.getHours() < hrs[2]) { return 2; }
       else if(now.getHours() == hrs[2] && now.getMinutes() < mins[2]) { return 2; }
       else if(now.getHours() == hrs[2] && now.getMinutes() >= mins[2]) { return 3; }
    
       else if(now.getHours() > hrs[2] && now.getHours() < hrs[3]) { return 3; }
       else if(now.getHours() == hrs[3] && now.getMinutes() < mins[3]) { return 3; }
       else if(now.getHours() == hrs[3] && now.getMinutes() >= mins[3]) { return 4; }
    
       else if(now.getHours() > hrs[3] && now.getHours() < hrs[4]) { return 4; }
       else if(now.getHours() == hrs[4] && now.getMinutes() < mins[4]) { return 4; }
       else if(now.getHours() == hrs[4] && now.getMinutes() >= mins[4]) { return 5; }
    
       else if(now.getHours() > hrs[4] && now.getHours() < hrs[5]) { return 5; }
       else if(now.getHours() == hrs[5] && now.getMinutes() < mins[5]) { return 5; }
       else if(now.getHours() == hrs[5] && now.getMinutes() >= mins[5]) { return 6; }
       else if(now.getHours() <= 23 && now.getMinutes() <= 59) { return 6; }
    }
```

Comment: Hi BakirGracic, did one of the answers below solve your problem? If so, please accept one of them using the green check mark. It lets the answerers know that your problem has been solved. If not, please expand on what problems you are continuing to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's better to use loops when processing arrays rather than a block of ifs or switch/case stuff. The benefits are many, but in particular, running the logic in a loop allows you to

- write it once.
- have an arbitrary number of cases.

I'm not sure if the `hrs` and `mins` in your project are specified as unrelated arrays or if this is a step you're taking prior to this step. It would be better to keep the hours and minutes together. In particular, it would be very easy to break your code if `hrs` ended up with an extra entry that `mins` didn't have. I wrote the example assuming that it would be fairly easy to pass the intervals in as an array of strings like "23:43". A comment in the code has a suggested method of building this string if you don't have it.

````js
function currentPeriod(intervals, now) {
  // Break these out so the methods are only called once.
  const nowHour = now.getHours();
  const nowMinute = now.getMinutes();
  
  // Iterate over all the intervals. If having the intervals broken into separate
  // arrays is a requirement of the project, they should be recombined like this:
  // ```
  // const intervals = hrs.map((h, i) => `${h}:${mins[i]}`);
  // ```
  for (let i = 0; i < intervals.length; i++) {
    // Get the hour and minute of the end of the interval.
    const [hour, minute] = intervals[i].split(":").map(a => +a);
    if (hour > nowHour) {
      // If the hour is after the current time, this is the correct interval. 
      return i;
    }
    else if (hour === nowHour && minute > nowMinute) {
      // If the hour is the same as the current time, and the minute is after
      // the current time, this is the correct interval.
      return i;
    }
  }
  // If the current time is after the last interval, say it's in the first
  // interval.
  return 0;
}

const intervals = ["03:13", "05:22", "12:54", "16:55", "20:23", "22:14"];

console.log("00:00", currentPeriod(intervals, new Date("2020-01-01T00:00:00")));
console.log("03:13", currentPeriod(intervals, new Date("2020-01-01T03:13:00")));
console.log("12:59", currentPeriod(intervals, new Date("2020-01-01T12:59:00")));
console.log("22:15", currentPeriod(intervals, new Date("2020-01-01T22:15:00")));
````

Notice: It's only required to see if the current time is before the next interval, because if it was before a previous interval, the loop would have exited on that one. This saves half the complexity of the solution as things aren't being checked twice.

Comment: This is it! Works flawlessly. I just couldn't come up with an idea how to do this and just asked here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As only the time of day needs to be considered we can get away by doing the calculations without using the full Date object. I transform the string based intervals into numbers and store them in `intv`. The time value to be tested (`dt`) can then be turned into an integer by multiplying the hours part by 100 and adding the minutes (variable `n`). The rest is done in the `while` loop where I walk through the intervals until I come to an `intv[p]` value that is greater than `n` (or until I reach the end of the array: `p<int.length` will then be `false`). The modulo operation (`%`) is necessary because for values of `n` greater than the last `intv` value I want the period number `p` to be 0 again (instead of 6 as it would have been in this example).

```js
function period(date){
 const intv = ["03:13", "05:22", "12:54", "16:55", "20:23", "22:14"].map(t=>+t.replace(":",""));
 let p=0,n=100*date.getHours()+date.getMinutes();
 while(n>=intv[p] && p<intv.length) p++
 return p%intv.length;
}

// testing:
let txt,dt=new Date();
for (i=0;i<48;i++){
 txt=dt.toLocaleString("de-DE").substr(-8)+"h: period ";
 console.log(txt+period(dt));
 dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes()+30);
}
```

Comment: There should be an explanation of the algorithm.

Comment: This answer is more clever and more efficient than mine. It's opaque as all get out though.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to provide an answer which uses DateTime objects and has readable code.

```js
let periods = ["03:13", "05:22", "12:54", "16:55", "20:23", "22:14"];

let periodDateTimeObjects = [];
periods.forEach(period => {
  let hours = Number(period.slice(0,2));
  let minutes = Number(period.slice(-2));
  periodDateTimeObjects.push(new Date().setUTCHours(hours, minutes, 0, 0));
});

let currentDateTime = new Date();
let periodStart = 0;
periodDateTimeObjects.forEach((periodDateTime, index) => {
  if (currentDateTime > periodDateTime) { periodStart = index; } 
});

let periodEnd = periodStart + 1;
if (periodEnd == periods.length) { periodEnd = 0; }
console.log("Time is now: " + currentDateTime.getHours() + ":" + currentDateTime.getMinutes() + " and current period is " + Number(periodStart + 1) + ": " + periods[periodStart] + " - " + periods[periodEnd]);
```

Comment: The result should be a single number for the period.

Comment: However OP wants it formatted in the end is up to him. The focus here is on method. Thank you for the opinion.